# How to display the items of a grid view?

Tags: android

I have a grid view and i have defined an array of 6 items(string) which have to be displayed in grid.

Grid_ViewActivity:

```
public class Grid_ViewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      //TextView selection;
      String[] characters=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.characters);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        GridView gv=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        //selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.simple_list_item,characters);
        gv.setAdapter(adapter);
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){



      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            //selection.setText(characters[position]);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ((TextView) v).getText()  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
        });
}
    }
```

main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<GridView
android:id="@+id/gridView1"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="20px"
android:horizontalSpacing="5px"
android:gravity="center"
android:columnWidth="40dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

/>
</LinearLayout>
```

simple_listitrm.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textSize="14pt"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting a null point exception.When i run this am application is force closed.Where i have gone wrong?

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: @Shani Goriwal  FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView,at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource,at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView,at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView,at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure,at android.view.View.measure
,at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins,at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout,at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical

Comment: ,at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure
,at android.view.View.measure
,at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins,at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure,at android.view.View.measure,at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical,at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure,at android.view.View.measure,at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins,

Comment: at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure,at android.view.View.measure,at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals,at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage, at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage,at android.os.Looper.loop,at android.app.ActivityThread.main, at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative,at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke, at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run,at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main,at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
,at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 String[] characters=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.characters);
```

`remove` this line from global and put inside `onCreate()` method

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView,at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource,at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView,at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView,at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure,at android.view.View.measure ,at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins,at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout,at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical –

Comment: ,at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure ,at android.view.View.measure ,at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins,at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure,at android.view.View.measure,at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical,at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure,at android.view.View.measure,at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins,

Comment: at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure,at android.view.View.measure,at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals,at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage, at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage,at android.os.Looper.loop,at android.app.ActivityThread.main, at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative,at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke, at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run,at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main,at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout ,at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use bellow code.

Change simple_listitrm.xml to this.

Change oncreate to this.

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    characters = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months);
    GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    // selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.test, characters);
    gv.setAdapter(adapter);
    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // selection.setText(characters[position]);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView,at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource,at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView,at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView,at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure,at android.view.View.measure ,at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins,at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout,at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical

Comment: ,at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure ,at android.view.View.measure ,at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins,at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure,at android.view.View.measure,at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical,at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure,at android.view.View.measure,at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins,

Comment: at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure,at android.view.View.measure,at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals,at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage, at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage,at android.os.Looper.loop,at android.app.ActivityThread.main, at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative,at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke, at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run,at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main,at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout ,at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource –

Comment: what should be the content of the test.xml?

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView XML exception means you don't supply what the ArrayAdapter expects. When you use this constructor:

```
 new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.a_layout_file, this.file)
```

R.Layout.a_layout_file must be the id of a xml layout file containing only a TextView(the TextView can't be wrapped by another layout, like a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc!),

something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
// other attributes of the TextView
/>
```

If you want your list row layout to be something a little different then a simple TextView widget use this constructor:

```
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.a_layout_file, 
    R.id.the_id_of_a_textview_from_the_layout, this.file)
```

where you supply the id of a layout that can contain various views, but also must contain a TextView with and id(the third parameter) that you pass to your ArrayAdapter so it can know where to put the Strings in the row layout.

Comment: Hi...Thanks.Igot the items displayed but on clicking the item i need a toast message to be displayed same as the item.How to do that?

Comment: my code is gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // selection.setText(characters[position]);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

Comment: @user2523879: are you got it??

Comment: @ Shani Goriwal Hi..Could u pls help me with the another question which i have posted regarding grid view with images??

Answer (score 0):

You have to change:

```
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        //selection.setText(characters[position]);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            characters[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
    });
```